# How to make dict always available to a particular template with Django/Jinja2?

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a template (using jinja2) that is used in lots of views (via {% include %} statements). The template will always require (amongst other data that changes, and will be passed in via the context) a dict, that is a constant. It would be cumbersome to add the dict to the context in every view that will potentially use the template.

I could add the dict as a global variable in the jinja2 env.globals, but that doesn’t seem like a particularly good idea either. It is only needed in one template in one app, not the entire project.

The Jinja2 documentation mentions template globals specific to a particular template, but I can’t figure out how to implement this with Django.

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: Some additional context.

The template provides some  information to be used in lots of other html documents (via the include tag). The positions of the lines and polygons are the same, but the colours are different. I don’t particularly want to hard-code all of the `x1=”20” x2=”30”` etc, so it would be useful to have all of this stored in a dict, and do something like the following:

```
{# Template to be included #}
<svg class="a" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
{% for i in range(10) %}        
    <line {{dict_always_available[i]}} class="{{info_passed_in_context[i]}}"></line>
{% endfor %}
</svg>
```

I don't want to have to pass dict_always_available into the context in every view that will potentially (but not necessarily) need it.

Comment: You could load the dict via xhr/ajax when its needed. seems like the most efficent solution for your problem.

Comment: Is this definitely Jinja rather than Django template language? In DTL the appropriate solution here would be an inclusion tag.

Comment: in DTL you could use context processors: https://matthewphiong.com/django-global-template-variable

Comment: @hansTheFranz The dict is used to apply constants, to some XML. I'm not sure doing this on the client side would be the best idea. I'll edit the post to add some more details, about the use case.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. Definitely jinja2. I'm not sure I understand how an inclusion tag would help here. Is it possible to include a python object such as a dict via an inclusion tag? I appologise for my ignorance if so. Could you expand on this at all. Thankyou :)

Comment: @DavidD. Yes. For consistency across the project, I'm using jinja2. Unfortunately it looks like there isn't support for context processors with jinja2. A good idea though.

Comment: Yes, an inclusion tag is a custom tag that renders an included template with a custom context. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I think my previous reply was mis-phrased. But can an inclusion tag return a dictionary (as apposed to just text). Otherwise I can’t see how it helps in this context.I’m sorry if I’m being dense. I’ve edited the original post to add details of what I am using this for. Thankyou for your help.